# PV panel power logger

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, power-electronics, solar-charge-controller, datalogger

I am working on installing a solar panel to charge a battery, and would like to create a power logger for testing the output from the charging circuit. I have seen resources on the internet for using small (<5W) panels using a data power logging shield on an arduino uno. I have larger (>50W) panels that I want to charge a 48V battery with.

My question is; is there any way I can record the power output without burning up the arduino? I can scale down the power to be able to read the voltage and current values on the arduino, I was thinking of using large power resistors because I know resistors are linear on the VI chart, so I can do some math and find the appropriate resistors/ratios, but I'm wondering if there's a cheaper and/or easier worthwhile way to do this.

I want to be able to scale it up (more panels, 200W, 300W) as well. I would also like to test with the charge controller in the circuit just to account for its power loss.

Please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your charge controller already measure voltage and current?

Comment: So add a shunt which will deal with larger currents.

Comment: @tomnexus no it does not